# Google API Rest: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens - error 404

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I get 404 errors while following step by step the "Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications" help page. [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

I use http/rest requests.

Everything is OK until step 5 : "Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens".

My request (POST or GET) returns a 404 error: "Not Found".
Here is my request, the same as in the guide:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?
code=4/_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX__XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX?&client_id=012345678912-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXX&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mydomain.com%3a50000%2fMyPage
```

Here is the related part of the guide:

> "To exchange an authorization code for an access token, call the
>   https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token endpoint and set the
>   following parameters:
>
> Fields
>
> code  The authorization code returned from the initial request.
>
> client_id The client ID obtained from the API Console.
>
> client_secret The client secret obtained from the API Console.
>
> redirect_uri  One of the redirect URIs listed for your project in the
>   API Console.
>
> grant_type    As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must
>   contain a value of authorization_code."

I think there is a problem with the service URL. Am I wrong?

Can any one provide the working URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A working request would be

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 233
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground
code=4%2FKxoYTS-jeq5-d6Lv7YvSz9ZrK0pJ_5lZsMExzNC1M0o&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=************&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Note that:-

1. It's a POST so the `code=` etc is the request body, not the URL.
2. Because it's a post, make sure the content-type header is correct, ie. "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
3. If the Access Code contains non-alphanumerics, eg. the "/" in the second character, it needs to be URL-encoded. This is often done by the http library you are using (eg. jquery, Angular $http, etc). Check the wire to see if it's being done correctly
4. I doubt very much that the Authorization Code contains a question mark. If (and only if) it does, it needs to be URL encoded.

Comment: The authorization code does contain a question mark and you are right: yes, there was a problem with the URL encoding in my code (I did not use the URL encoded variable!) It was obvious in my code but the 404 error made me focus on a false trail.

Answer (score 3):

Step two in the auth flow is a HTTP POST.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
code={The code from step one}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri={RedirectURI}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The main difference I see is that you have a `?` tacked on the end of the URL which is not needed.  Remember you need to post the string exactly as I have show it with the &'s as a string.

This is my tutorial on [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) it might help

Comment: I tried GET and POST and had the same isue.

The '?' char is part of the code string received from google.
I noticed it to and tried to remove it but still had the 404 error.
I left it in my question because it was part of the code string google returned me and because it removing it changed nothing.

Two minutes ago I managed to build a workaround solution but it is not satisfying: it mixes REST API and Google API for .Net Client.

I will have a look at you tutorial, I am sure it will improve my %$!£¨#@% of a code.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Why don't you just use the Google .Net client library to begin with?   Why are you trying to do this manually?   The first part of the auth flow should not have returned a url to you with a ? it should only return an authentication code.   Which looks like this 4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI    I suspect that you are ripping it out of the title and grabbing the ? as well which you shouldn't be you should only be grabbing the code.

Comment: My environment is complicated, not full .Net. The project is mostly an ASP.Net WebForm "web site" mixed with old classic ASP VB Script pages. And using the REST API seemed so simple, but for this one problem.