# 404 Error on Google OAuth API Token Request

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to get a token from the Google OAuth api. I have already successfully been able to get the temporary auth code.

However, my requests are returning a 404 error, with the normal Google "That's an error" 404 page. Here is my Python code:

```
data = {
    "code":auth_code,
    "client_id":client_id,
    "client_secret":client_secret,
    "redirect_uri":redirect_uri,
    "grant_type":"authorization_code"
    }
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
r = requests.post("https://googleapis.com/oauth/v4/token",data=data,headers=headers)
```

I get the same error no matter if I url-encode my parameters or not (I think the requests library does it anyway).

Here are the data I am sending in more detail (censored of course)

```
'client_id':'2-------------------------------------------0.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'client_secret': '5----------------------p',
'code': '4/A-------------------------- ... ------------------------------------fGE#',
'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost'
```

I understand the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828358/google-api-rest-exchange-authorization-code-for-refresh-and-access-tokens-err) is very similar to mine but all the solutions provided either don't work (url encoding) or don't apply (everything else).

I am using [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps) official documentation for reference.

This is probably very obvious, like most of the questions I ask here.

Edit - I tried

```
data = "code="+auth_code+"&client_id="+client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

...which returned a 400. With or without url-encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

I didn't add my redirect uri to the list of authorized ones as the option doesn't appear if you set your app type to "Other". I set it to "Web Application" (even though it isn't) and added my redirect uri and that fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

For me the issue was that I was sending a GET. You have to send a POST.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why wouldn't they return something like "405 Method not allowed" - it would be way more helpful ...

Comment: Thanks bro, saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet lists "https://googleapis.com/oauth/v4/token".

The token endpoint is "https://googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token".

Comment: Ok, scrap that. "r = requests.post("https://googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",data=data,headers=headers)" is 404ing as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my edge case, I was requesting the token pass

```
            val tokenRequest = Request.Builder()
            .method(
                "POST",
                "".toRequestBody("application/x-www-form-urlencoded".toMediaType())
            )
```

The snippet above didn't work until I changed "POST" to "post".